# La versión de PHP no es compatible con la aplicación

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

tengo un error al instalar Wordpress en un hosting de donWeb. Me sale el error del tiulo. Cuando voy a cambiar la version de PHP no me salen otras opciones, es decir, no me deja cambiarla

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo has visto con tu proveedor?? La instalación de Wordpress dice que versión de sus componentes necesita, debes configurar así tu hosting